# c# Hide function from Designer

Tags: c#, designer, attributes

I have a function that causes an exception in the designer. Can I avoid the call of the function if the designer loads it. Is there an attribute or something that is better than try catch?

Some more details:
I mean the visual studio designer for win forms. My form is using a signleton wich calls LoadProject() on initialize. Now I want to avoid that the designer calls the LoadProject() function.

Comment: Which designer - the Windows Forms designer? And which method/function is it that the designer calls?

Comment: Agree.  I'll give you a +1 to counteract if you improve your question to be both detailed and specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of detecting whether or not you are in design mode:

- Check the value of the [DesignMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx) property of the control. This does not work in a constructor of a control though, as it only returns true if the control has been sited, which does not happen until after the control has been created. It also has a [bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=117130) whereby a custom control inside a custom control will always return false
- Check whether the current application's path contains `devenv.exe` using `Application.ExecutablePath.ToLower().IndexOf("devenv.exe")`. If is does, the control is being instantiated by Visual Studio. A bit horrible, but it works.
- Check `LicenseManager.UsageMode` for the value `LicenseUsageMode.Designtime` (have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166226/detecting-design-mode-from-a-controls-constructor/1166547#1166547) to [Detecting design mode from a Control’s constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166226/detecting-design-mode-from-a-controls-constructor) for more details). Note that **this does work in the constructor**.

Wrapping the call to your function in any of these checks should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is WinForms - You can check if you are currently in DesignMode and just have your function return immediately.

There are some complexities that are fully explained [in this article](http://decav.com/blogs/andre/archive/2007/04/18/1078.aspx) including a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You might try looking at **[this article on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx)** about using the **DesignMode** property.  This might help you out.  You can wrap your code that throws an exception in this in a conditional that avoids the code at design time.

Please note this will **not work in the constructor**, because the designer has to instantiate the object and then sets the property.