# Are there any caveats to swapping out DesignMode for LicenseManager.UsageMode in a WinForms UserControl constructor?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

If you have a Form that displays data, one thing you can do is reference `this.DesignMode` in the constructor  to avoid populating it in the designer:

```
public partial class SetupForm : Form
{
    private SetupItemContainer container = new SetupItemContainer();

    public SetupForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (!this.DesignMode)
        {
            this.bindingSource1.DataSource = this.container;
            this.Fill();
        }
    }
 }
```

However, if you decide to re-write that form as a UserControl, keeping the same constructor logic, something unexpected happens - `this.DesignMode` is always false no matter what.  This leads to the designer invoking your logic that's meant to happen at runtime.

I just found a comment on a blog post that seem to give a fix to this but it references functionality of the [LicenseManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.licensemanager.aspx) class as a replacement that works as expected in a UserControl.

So for a UserControl I can do:

```
public partial class AffiliateSetup : UserControl
{
    private AffiliateItemContainer container = new AffiliateItemContainer();

    public AffiliateSetup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Runtime)
        {
            this.bindingSource1.DataSource = this.container;
            this.Fill();
        }
    }
}
```

Does using the `LicenseManager` instead of `DesignMode` have any caveats or implications that might dissuade me from putting in my production code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to someone who posted a comment on [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1166547/116923), using `LicenseManager` doesn't work in an `OnPaint` method.

Comment: That's pretty obscure.  It sounds almost like it doesn't work in `OnPaint` because of a "circular reference" (Perhaps `OnPaint` won't fire in the first place if the licensing model is not correct?)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree, it is pretty obscure. I've not tested it so cannot confirm it is the case, but the comment has two upvotes so I assume that at least two people have encountered the behaviour.