# Accessing static data in UserControl constructor bug in designer

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I need to access external data at the loading of a UserControl (in constructor or load event).

It works fine in run mode but in VS Designer mode it throws a NullReferenceException because in the instance the static data is not instantiated.

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Problem when accessing external data
        Foo( AnotherClass.MyStaticData );
    }

    private void Foo(Data d)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

How can I execute the line `Foo( AnotherClass.MyStaticData );` from the control ?

Comment: what  CtrlsSymbolsGrid.cs do

Comment: It doesn't look like that's where the error is. The error is in `CtrlSymbolsGrid_Load`.

Comment: @K.B It has no real importance, this problem occured when I changed the way to access the static data.

Comment: @JohnSaunders you're right, the screen shows when I tried to move the line in the Load event

Answer (score 1):

In your custom controls, you can check if they're in design mode or not and behave differently. For example, you can provide a default value instead of your missing static class property, so that the designer can render your desing-time control.

You have a lot of information about this in this page:

[Custom Design-time Control Features in Visual Studio .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164048.aspx)

The property is [ISite.DesigMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isite.designmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Rectification : the `DesignMode`does not help if the control is used in an other form, have you an idea ?

Comment: Give a deeper explanation of the problem. I don't understand what it means to "use the control in an other form". I've used it with WebForms, not WinForms, without any problem when I nest controls inside other controls.

Comment: I meant use the `UserControl` as a .NET component in an other `Form`. The constructor of the UserForm makes the calling Form throw an exception

Comment: Please, edit your question, giving a more detailed explanation of what you do: the full code for your user control, and what you do to have the exception thrown. If I can understand and reproduce it, probably I´ll be able to give you more hints.

Comment: Thank you JotaBe, you sown me the way and now I've found the final solution, I write the solution in original post :)

Comment: Glad you found it, but never do that!! :) When you find the answer don't add it to the question: answer yourself and accept your own answer as valid. This will make your Q&A useful for anybody with the same problem. Addind the A inside the Q isn't helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I answer myself, this is the solution :

Using `ISite.DesignMode` is apparently not working in a context of UserControl so I've found a reliable solution here : [Detecting design mode from a Control's constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166226/detecting-design-mode-from-a-controls-constructor)

```
bool designMode = (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it is impossible to access the actual static data in the Designer. Thus, the only solution is to supply a dummy at design time. Combining the answers of 56ka and JotaBe, here is how to solve the problem:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
      
        if(LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)
        {// Use a dummy value for display at design time.
            Foo(desginDummyValue); 
        }
        else
        {// Use the real static data only at runtime
            Foo( AnotherClass.MyStaticData ); 
        }
    }
}
```