# Using custom TreeView class in View

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a custom `TreeView` class like so:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace My.Namespace
{
    public partial class SimpleTree : System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
    {
        private TreeNode topNode; ////////// 
        private TreeNode lowerNode1;
        private TreeNode lowerNode2;
        private TreeNode lowerNode3;

        public SimpleTree()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BuildTree();

            TreeViewEventArgs eventArgs = new TreeViewEventArgs(topNode, TreeViewAction.Unknown);

            this.ExpandAll(); // must be after adding the nodes

        }

        private void BuildTree()
        {
            this.Name = "Simple Tree";

            topNode = new TreeNode("Top Node");
            topNode.Name = "Top Node"
            this.Nodes.Add(topNode);

            lowerNode1 = new TreeNode("Lower Node 1");
            lowerNode1.Name = "Lower Node 1";
            topNode.Nodes.Add(lowerNode1);

            lowerNode2 = new TreeNode("Lower Node 2");
            lowerNode2.Name = "Lower Node 2";
            topNode.Nodes.Add(lowerNode2);

            lowerNode3 = new TreeNode("Lower Node 3");
            lowerNode3.Name = "Lower Node 3";
            topNode.Nodes.Add(lowerNode3);
        }
        // This is a simplified example, much more functionality here in real code
    }
}
```

I include this SimpleTree in ProjectView.cs (that has many components).
In ProjectView.Designer.cs, there is this:

```
private SimpleTreeView trvSimple;
this.trvSimple = new My.Namespace.SimpleTreeView();

this.trvSimple.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
this.trvSimple.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 65);
this.trvSimple.Name = "trvSimple";
this.trvSimple.Scrollable = false;
this.trvSimple.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(128, 109);
this.trvSimple.TabIndex = 1;
this.trvSimple.Text = "trvSimple";
this.trvSimple.BeforeCollapse += new System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewCancelEventHandler(this.trvSimple_BeforeCollapse);
this.trvSimple.BeforeSelect += new System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewCancelEventHandler(this.trvSimple_BeforeSelect);
```

This all works. The tree looks like:

> Top Node
>   -- Lower Node 1
>   -- Lower Node 2
>   -- Lower Node 3

However, when I change anything else in ProjectView, the Visual Editor then adds this code to ProjectView.Designer.cs

```
System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode treeNode1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Lower Node 1");
System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode treeNode2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Lower Node 2");
System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode treeNode3 = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Lower Node 3");
System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode treeNode6 = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Top Node", new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode[] {
treeNode1,
treeNode2,
treeNode3});
```

So now it looks like this:

> Top Node
>   -- Lower Node 1
>   -- Lower Node 2
>   -- Lower Node 3
>   Top Node
>   -- Lower Node 1
>   -- Lower Node 2
>   -- Lower Node 3

How do I prevent this code from being added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably shouldn't do this from a custom control.  It would be simpler to just populate a TreeView control at run time in the form's constructor.

If you still want to do this from your custom control, you can try only adding the nodes when you are [not design mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1166226/719186):

```
public SimpleTree() {
  if (LicenseManager.UsageMode != LicenseUsageMode.Designtime) {
    BuildTree();
  }
  this.ExpandAll();
}
```

The other possibility is to just override the Nodes collection and force it to not serialize the data at design time:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public new TreeNodeCollection Nodes {
  get {
    return base.Nodes;
  }
}
```

This would make adding or editing any nodes at design time pointless since it wouldn't save anything.