# How to make Android ignore specific code for layout previews

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I have a compound view `CheckboxesView`, where I have some checkboxes:

**CheckboxesView**

checkboxes_view_layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android...>
    <CheckBox
       ...
    />
    <CheckBox
       ...
    />
    ...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the respective class for this view, I have the following `init`

```
init {
    View.inflate(context, R.layout.checkboxes_view_layout, this)

    if(valueExists()) {
        hideCheckboxes()
    }
}
```

---

I use this `CheckboxesView` in an `MyActivity`, which obviously has its own Layout `my_activity_layout`

**MyActivity**

my_activity_layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android=.../>
    ....

    <CheckboxesView
                    android:id="@+id/checkboxesView"
                    .../>

    ....
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

`CheckboxesView.valueExists()` checks for some value that is saved in preferences and if `valueExists` returns false, I make `checkboxesView` invisible by calling `CheckboxesView.hideCheckboxes()` as seen in the code above.

In the app, this works perfectly. The preferences value is checked and if necessary the checkboxes are hidden. However, I don't want this to happen when I look at the preview of `my_activity_layout`. Obviously the preview of `my_activity_layout` calls `CheckboxesView.init` which checks for the non-existing preference which causes the view to never be visible in the preview.

---

Is there a way for me to have a piece of code that is **not** called for a layout preview? For example:

```
init {
    View.inflate(context, R.layout.checkboxes_view_layout, this)

    if(System.NotAPreview()) {    
        if(valueExists()) {
            hideCheckboxes()
        }
    }
}
```

---

For readers who are somewhat familiar with C# and Visual Studio, I basically want to do something in the lines of [detecting design mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166226/detecting-design-mode-from-a-controls-constructor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
View.isInEditMode()
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#isInEditMode()

A view is usually in edit mode when displayed within a developer tool.

If the view is drawn by a visual user interface builder this method should return true.

In your specific case:

```
if (!View.isInEditMode()) {
    if (valueExists()) {
        hideCheckboxes()
    } 
}
```