# Panel onPaint render artefacts

Tags: c#, onpaint

I created Panel class "GpanelBorder" which draw border in custom panel with code:

```
namespace GetterControlsLibary
{
    public class GpanelBorder : Panel
    {
        private Color colorBorder;
        public GpanelBorder()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(
                new Pen(
                    new SolidBrush(colorBorder), 8),
                    e.ClipRectangle);
        }

        public Color BorderColor
        {
            get
            {
                return colorBorder;
            }
            set
            {
                colorBorder = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Works fine but when i in design mode, mouse click inside panel and move mouse or drag other control over this panel, artifacts are created (picture below)

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: See if any of the flags play bad with designer, if so then detect design mode and set flags accordingly : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166226/detecting-design-mode-from-a-controls-constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.ClipRectangle` parameter does NOT necessarily represent the entire area of your control to be painted within.  It may represent a SMALLER portion of your control indicating just that portion needs to be repainted.  You can use the "clip rectangle" to redraw only a portion of your control in situations where it would be too costly to compute and repaint the entire control.  If that situation doesn't apply to you, then use the [ClientRectangle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle?view=netcore-3.1) to get the bounds of your entire control and use that to draw your border.  Also, you are LEAKING a PEN and a SOLIDBRUSH.  You need to `.Dispose()` of those resources when you're done with them.  This is best done with a `using` block:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    using (SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(colorBorder), 8))
    {
        using (Pen p = new Pen(sb))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, this.ClientRectangle);
        }
    }
}
```

You may need to create a new Rectangle based on ClientRectangle and adjust that to your liking before drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Works great!

but corectly code is

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            using (SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(colorBorder))
            {
                using (Pen p = new Pen(colorBorder, 2))
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, this.ClientRectangle);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's not how you had it originally written (look back at your code!)...but I'm glad you figured it out.  ;)  If my post below was helpful, then give it an upvote or an accept.