# How to flip a User Control added in a picturebox by 180 degrees?

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, picturebox, togglebutton

I'm adding a control to a picturebox. This control is a component, precisely it's a toggle switch [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38432140/2497570). I'd like this control to be vertical and not horizontal .

So, since objects can't be rotated or flipped, I found a way to flip the picturebox image with:

```
PictureBox1.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone)
    PictureBox1.Refresh()
```

The error I'm getting at RunTime is:

> System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.Image.get returned Nothing

Endeed the control is not an image so is there a way to flip the control inside of the picturebox by 180 degrees?
Also, You think there is a way to know when the value of the toggle switch is on or off?
Thanks

Comment: If you want it to be vertical, don't you mean "rotate by 90 degrees"? Anyway, what you're doing here is valid for a bitmap, but you're dealing with a control. Just because it's in a PictureBox doesn't mean it's an image. You can't just rotate it, you just need to paint it differently in the `OnPaint` method (i.e., using a different path).

Comment: A control draws itself. For that switch to be displayed vertically, there would have to be code inside that control to draw it vertically. In that context, you would generally add a property to control the orientation and then read that property inside the `OnPaint` method and draw appropriate. You need to understand that drawing code and determine how to modify it to draw the way you want.

Comment: *"You think there is a way to know when the value of the toggle switch is on or off"*. Well that just shows that you've not made an effort to understand the code. It's a custom `CheckBox` control. Do you really not know how to use a `CheckBox`? It's even in the drawing code.

Comment: Just for curiosity purposes, It would be possible to "convert" what picturebox is displaying ( eventhough is a control or whatever )to an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned above, extend the control to have it drawn either horizontally or vertically.

```vb
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class ToggleSwitch
    Inherits CheckBox

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New

        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint Or
                 ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
        UpdateStyles()
        Padding = New Padding(6)
    End Sub

    Private _orientation As Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
    Public Property Orientation As Orientation
        Get
            Return _orientation
        End Get
        Set(value As Orientation)
            _orientation = value

            Dim max = Math.Max(Width, Height)
            Dim min = Math.Min(Width, Height)

            If value = Orientation.Vertical Then
                Size = New Size(min, max)
            Else
                Size = New Size(max, min)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    'Fix by: @41686d6564
    <Browsable(False),
    Bindable(False),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden),
    EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>
    Public Overrides Property AutoSize As Boolean
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
        Dim g = e.Graphics

        g.Clear(BackColor)
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
        g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half

        Dim p = Padding.All
        Dim r = 0
        Dim rec As Rectangle

        Using gp = New GraphicsPath
            If _orientation = Orientation.Vertical Then
                r = Width - 2 * p
                gp.AddArc(p, p, r, r, -180, 180)
                gp.AddArc(p, Height - r - p, r, r, 0, 180)
                r = Width - 1
                rec = New Rectangle(0, If(Checked, Height - r - 1, 0), r, r)
                'Or
                'rec = New Rectangle(0, If(Checked, 0, Height - r - 1), r, r)
                'To get the ON on top.
            Else
                r = Height - 2 * p
                gp.AddArc(p, p, r, r, 90, 180)
                gp.AddArc(Width - r - p, p, r, r, -90, 180)
                r = Height - 1
                rec = New Rectangle(If(Checked, Width - r - 1, 0), 0, r, r)
            End If

            gp.CloseFigure()

            g.FillPath(If(Checked, Brushes.DarkGray, Brushes.LightGray), gp)
            g.FillEllipse(If(Checked, Brushes.Green, Brushes.WhiteSmoke), rec)
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

[image: SOQ64236248]

As for the second part of your question, please read [CheckBox.Checked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked?view=netcore-3.1) property and [CheckBox.CheckedChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged?view=netcore-3.1) event.

Impelemntation example:

```vb
Private Sub ToggleSwitch1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToggleSwitch1.CheckedChanged
    If ToggleSwitch1.Checked Then
        'ToDo with ON state...
    Else
        'ToDo with OFF state..
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks .
Just a simple question. If I want to switch on towards up, what should i change?

Comment: @Mattia You are welcome. Just toggle the `Checked` property. Like: `ToggleSwitch1.Checked = True`

Comment: Hi dr.null, I don't mean that. As you can see, you are switching on the toggle moving it down, While I'm asking how to make it the opposite way.

Comment: @Mattia ah I see. It makes more sense your way. In the vertical painting, just replace the line `rec = New Rectangle(0, If(Checked, Height - r - 1, 0), r, r)` with `rec = New Rectangle(0, If(Checked, 0, Height - r - 1), r, r)`. I added that commented in the code.

Comment: Oh thanks that s exactly what I was looking for. I appreciated your help.

Comment: Nice work. Upvoted. There's one issue though: changing the value of `AutoSize` in the constructor will have no effect on instances added at design-time. To get around this, you may decorate the class with `<ToolboxItem(GetType(ToolboxItem))>` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48353592/8967612).

Comment: A better approach would be to override the `AutoSize` property. Then, you have two options. Option 1) Make it always return false and hide it from the designer and IntelliSense (by decorating it with `<Browsable(False)>`, `<Bindable(False)>`, `<DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>`, and `<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>`). Option 2) Implement your own autosizing logic in the property's setter.