# WinForms Bug? Why my UserControl.Load is being called when I drag and drop the Control on a Form?

Tags: winforms

this problem is annoying me and I took too much time to get it.

I'm very new to WinForms, so, maybe I'm missing something.

Whenever I drag'n'drop my UserControl to the form, it's Load event is being called (not the constructor).

it is very easy to reproduce.

Edit: I'm using .net core 3.1

1 - Create a new Project

2 - Create a new UserControl

3 - Add a Load Event and force an exception inside this method

4 - Build and try to add the control to the mainForm, the exception will raise.

The method is being called even with my project stoped.

For now, I just comment the method, build and add the Control to my forms, then I uncomment again and evertything works normally. There is no exception in Runtime and I can see the control in the desing. The only problem is to drag it to the form.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is suppost to happen.  The UC is operating in design mode only when you are actually modifying its content with the designer, when you drop it on a form then it works like any other control in the toolbox.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336817/how-can-i-detect-whether-a-user-control-is-running-in-the-ide-in-debug-mode-or

Comment: Oh, thank you! That was very strange to me, I thought the Events rans only in Runtime.